# OpenSSL RAND_poll 'good enough'

Tags: random, c

We are using OpenSSL for generating IV's and other random data. We initialize it using `RAND_poll` and, on Windows, `RAND_screen`.

The question is though, if the seed generated by those methods is good enough (`RAND_screen` at least sounds to me like it is). Also, I was wondering how exactly `RAND_poll` works, as I could not find much documentation about it ant if it does behave differently depending on platform, like `RAND_screen` which is only available on Windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`RAND_bytes()` automatically calls `RAND_poll()` if it has not already been done at least once. So you do not have to call it yourself. `RAND_poll()` feeds on what the operating system provides: on Linux, Solaris, FreeBSD and similar Unix-like systems, it will use `/dev/urandom` (or `/dev/random` if there is no `/dev/urandom`) to obtain a cryptographically secure initial seed; on Windows, it will call `CryptGenRandom()` for the same effect.

`RAND_screen()` is provided by OpenSSL only for backward compatibility with (much) older code which may call it (that was *before* OpenSSL used proper OS-based seed initialization).

So the "normal" way of dealing with `RAND_poll()` and `RAND_screen()` is to call neither. Just use `RAND_bytes()` and be happy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In regards to your suggestion to call neither, the problem under Windows is that `RAND_poll` can take some time and will block our UI. So we call it upon initialization, which works for us. Secondly, do you know what will be the source of randomness on Symbian and if that one is reliable?